# Can Table-Driven Lexers "lex" Multi-Dimensional Arrays?

Tags: compiler-construction, lexer, dfa

I've been thinking about how one would go to implement this, but I've found no really good answer.

Essentially, the problem I've run into is that given an arbitrarily large dimension for an array, there would have to be an equal amount of Lexer States to keep track of the depth, so this got me thinking about how expressive Table-Driven Lexers can really be.

It's obvious to me that DFAs cannot count. So since DFAs (Discrete Finite Automatas) cannot count, at least not beyond a hard-coded limit, how do TDLs support multi-dimensional arrays?

Do languages have a hard-cap on how many nested arrays you can have, or do they use hand-made Lexers to account for the need to count?

Comment: In my experience, the lexer - or even the parser - does not count - they rely on the following semantic analysis stage to check that all (in this case) array bounds are valid.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError When people say that "DFAs can't count" they're usually talking about their inability to express conditions like matching brackets (i.e. counting the number of currently opened brackets). And of course the parser very much does do that. I don't think OP was talking about checking array bounds (or I've severely misunderstood the question).

Comment: Why would you do this just with a lexer? To you, what does the phrase "lexical analysis" mean?

Comment: @rici To me, a lexer simply spits out a series of tokens from plain text. A token being a pair, the grammar entity, and its value.

Comment: @novicegrammer: Exactly. So it's not the tool which assembles a complicated object like an array. You don't need to know the index of an array element to know what kind of a token `42` is.

Comment: @rici Of course, then the tokens would need to pass through a parser and hopefully be used to build a semantically correct AST. Of course I'm not trying to compile a language with *just* a lexer, but from what I understand lexing is the first step.

Comment: @rici I see what you mean. You're suggesting the "dimension" determining phase be tackled during semantic analysis (AST)?

Comment: Yes, the logic which deals with dimensions and indices would be in semantic analysis, *after* the AST is built. That is, involving neither the lexer nor the parser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213734/discussion-between-novicegrammer-and-rici).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that when you talk about lexing arrays, you're talking about array literals like `[x, y]` or array initializers like `{x, y}`. Neither of these would be lexed as a single token. They'd be lexed as `[`, `x`, `,`, `y`, `]` or `{`, `x`, `,`, `y`, `}` respectively. That applies to multi-dimensional arrays as well as one-dimensional ones.

Note that if you were to try to turn them into a single token, you'd run into problems even with single-dimensional arrays. Since they can usually contain arbitrary expressions, recognizing them as a single token would mean that the lexer has to parse arbitrary exceptions, which also involves arbitrary nesting and is clearly out of the lexer's scope anyway.

Comment: What I'm hinting at is things like char x[][][], etc. I guess lexing and then parsing array literals, instead of array identifiers will also lead to the same problem.

Comment: @Novicegrammer: If what you're worried about is agreement between the declared array size and the size and shape of an initializer, then you are correct that the parser will not reject erroneous programs. So what? There are lots of erroneous programs which the grammar won't reject. (Use of uninitialised variables, for example.)